# Symfony: There are no commands defined in the "ckeditor" namespace

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, composer-php, bundle

I have the following error when i try to install the IvoryCKEditorBundle

```
php bin/console ckeditor:install

[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
There are no commands defined in the "ckeditor" namespace.
```

composer.json:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.3.*",
         //....
```

Comment: what are you trying to do with that `php bin/console ckeditor:install` command? As I see you have ckeditor in required dependencies so just run `composer install` to install it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. So I just tried to go to the next step (install assets) and it works.

When you do the composer require, **it's already installed.**

You don't need to do the command  : php bin/console ckeditor:install

Answer (score 2):

I bet you have version 4.0.6 installed too, you can just skip that step as you can see in the docs: https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryCKEditorBundle/blob/4.0.6/Resources/doc/installation.rst.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line of code:

> config/bundles.php:
>
> return [
> // ...
> FOS\CKEditorBundle\FOSCKEditorBundle::class => ['all' => true], ];

At this point run again:

> php bin/console ckeditor:install

It should be work

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -1):

go here, and read and follow the docs, as anyone would do

http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/IvoryCKEditorBundle/installation.html

**But also,   i suggest you study up on composer and symfony first ....**

Comment: i start study IvoryCKEditorBundle with this cookbook as anyone would do: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/IvoryCKEditorBundle/installation.html, I did not encounter any problems with the first and second step but the third one "Download CKEditor"  returned an error message, that's why i came here to find some help